# How to set seller name similar to app name at itunes?

Tags: ios, iphone, itunes

Ive seen many apps having seller/developer name similar to their app name.

For example app "xyz" with developer "xyz"

I am developing my first iPhone application, and I dont want itunes to show my full name as seller name. I would love if there is a way to do so without having a company.

What is the easiest way?

Comment: First better to provide your code snippet whatever you tried

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible without being a registered business. Only legitimate businesses can use a business name. This is apple's policy in place for legal reasons. You will have to live with it being your real name. Similar to how I must use my parent's name because I am not yet 18 years old.

Comment: So any user showing developer instead of seller name should have business?

Comment: Yes. Apple only allows registered businesses to make business accounts for legal reasons. It is not worth it to do such a thing unless you are bringing hefty profits from your apps or have a legitimate company you are selling with.